# Having problems connecting to file shares on Big Sur from a Catalina Machine

Tags: network, permission

Relative newbie to Mac.
I have an iMac running Catalina V10.15.3 and a recently purchased Mac mini now running Big Sur 11.2.

The problem is I cannot connect to some shared folders on the Mac mini from the iMac. The only ones that do connect are my user share and the macOS boot disk.

I get the message "There was a problem connecting to the server xxxx. You do not have permission to access this server"

I have checked for permissions as far as my limited knowledge allows, but am stuck. Google gives me zero clues !!

Any help would be much appreciated

PS I can connect to all shares on the Catalina machine from the Big Sur machine.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried giving `smbd` (/usr/sbin/smbd) full disk access in "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access" on Big Sur?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said I am very new to OSX. I cannot find smbd under /usr/sbin. All I have is authserver!. Sorry to be so thick

Comment: "authserver" is the only folder in that directory.  It seems you are not seeing the hundreds of files there (which also is a symptom of file sharing not working as expected and would be fixed by giving `smbd` full disk access - are you on a different Mac when you look for smbd?  If yes, can you see the files via "Remote Login" {ssh in Terminal}, also in the Sharing preferences? Or screen sharing?)

Comment: @Redarm you should post this as an answer. I've been searching for the answer for this for hours and this fixed it. Thank you!!!